# Target a class whether or not it has a number in the name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm struggling a bit with this : let's say I have a class in the body `<body class="video page">` and in my page I have a pagination which add a number like this `<body class="video-2 page">` at each page. I would like to target the class `video` whether or not it has a number in order to apply some jquery if the condition is filled.

How do I do that?

Comment: “I would like to target the class video whether or not it has a number” — if it has a number (or indeed anything else) appended, it’s not the class `video`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would split the classes like `class="video two page"` so that you can still address both classes separately. Nevertheless you can do something like

```
$('body[class*=video]')
```

Comment: Although that does assume he’s not going to use a class like `no-video`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this attribute selector to select elements that have a class attribute starting with `video-`:

```
[class^="video-"]
```

But for this to work, you’d have to make sure that the `video-` class is the first one in the element’s `class` attribute (see http://jsfiddle.net/Czyep/).

It might be better to have the `video` class and the pagination class be separate, e.g.:

```
<body class="video page-2 page">
```

Comment: The `page` class is not related to the pagination it's just a class for pages which are not the index but like i replied to Jan below i'll keep in mind this usefull tip, thank you :]

Comment: @Tonani: ah, I see — I’ve amended my example accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("body").not(".video");
```

Should select all bodies wich end with a number. You could also do:

```
if($("body").is("[class$='video-'")) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried something like this this?

```
$('.video,.video-'+pageNumber).dosomething()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [attribute starts with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/):

```
$("body[class^='video']");
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I have understood your question correctly I would suggest that you use concatenation in your selector.

I assume that you are aware that you have specified two classes on your body tag namely video and page or video-2 and page. And I therefore assume that page is significant in your selection and should be included in your selector.

Therefore I would use this syntax whilst not as neat as some syntax it is very clear what is going on. Obviously you would need to incorporate this into what ever logic is driving your page selection.

```
var suffix = "";

$(".video" + suffix + ".page").dosomething();  // select <body class="video page">

suffix = "-2";

$(".video" + suffix + ".page").dosomething();  // select <body class="video-2 page">
```

Note that there should be no space between the classes in the selector because they have been declared in the same tag in the html.

Had you specified something like

```
<body class="video">    // body wrapper
    <div class="page">  // page wrapper
    </div>
</body>
```

Then a space would be required as you are then looking to match on div page within body with class video or video-2 as appropriate.

```
suffix = "-2";

$(".video" + suffix + " .page").dosomething();  // select <body class="video-2"><div class="page">
```